# How to identify columns in a dataframe and replace them with new columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame

`df <- data.frame(c(1:5), c(6:10),  rep(1,length(5)), c(11:15), rep(4,length(5)))`

I want to find all columns which have numbers that are all equal,
eg. (all 1 or all 4).

After finding these columns, I would like to replace
these columns with others that has 1 in the first row and 0 in all the others rows
like this:

[image]

I used this to find the columns

```
i1 <- sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x)) >1)
```

I do not know how to replace those columns with the new ones.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `apply` solution:

```
df <- setNames(
    data.frame(c(1:5), c(6:10),  rep(1,length(5)), c(11:15), rep(4,length(5))),
    letters[1:5])

df_new <- apply(df, 2, function(col) 
    if(length(unique(col)) == 1) c(1, rep(0, length(col)-1)) else col)

df_new
     a  b c  d e
[1,] 1  6 1 11 1
[2,] 2  7 0 12 0
[3,] 3  8 0 13 0
[4,] 4  9 0 14 0
[5,] 5 10 0 15 0
```

Note that the output is now a matrix, which may actually be a better fit if your data really is all the same type across all columns; however, if you want a data.frame, `as.data.frame(df_new)` will do that for you.